# Update value for a repeating UILabel with loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, uilabel

I have labels that will hold the name and value of an array `items = [MyItems]()`. Where

```
struct MyItems {
    name: String!
    value: Int!
}
```

The labels are `titleLabel1` and `valueLabel1`. I have 6 of these labels that take a value from the array which has more than 6 values.

Currently I am using a `for` loop like:

```
var items = [MyItems]()
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    items = loadItemsFromAPI()
    populateFields()
}
func populateFields() {
    for var i = 0; i < 6 && i < items.count; i++ {
      switch i {
           case 0:
               titleLabel1.text = items[i].name
               valueLabel1.text = "items[i].value"
           case 1:
               titleLabel1.text = items[i].name
               valueLabel1.text = "items[i].value"
           case 2:
               titleLabel1.text = items[i].name
               valueLabel1.text = "items[i].value"                
           case 3:
               titleLabel1.text = items[i].name
               valueLabel1.text = "items[i].value"
           case 4:
               titleLabel1.text = items[i].name
               valueLabel1.text = "items[i].value"   
           case 5:
               titleLabel1.text = items[i].name
               valueLabel1.text = "items[i].value"  
           default:
               print("Unexpected value encounteredValue: \(i)")
               break
           }
      }
}
```

My question is is there any way to loop over the labels to assign the values instead of this lengthy way?

like

```
for var i = 0; i < 6; i++ {
    titleLabel + "i-1".text = items[i].name
}
```

In theory that's what I have in mind only if it was possible to have a short cleaner code.

Comment: I assume you want to use a different label for every case instead of the same?

Comment: Do you want each case to have a different label? Or are you trying to update the label content every second, say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the labels in an array:

```
let titleCollection = [titleLabel1, titleLabel2, titleLabel3, titleLabel4, titleLabel5, titleLabel6]
let valueCollection = [valueLabel1, valueLabel2, valueLabel3, valueLabel4, valueLabel5, valueLabel6]
```

Using zip to add the text to the labels safely:

```
zip(titleCollection, items).forEach { $0.0.text = $0.1.name }
zip(valueCollection, items).forEach { $0.0.text = String($0.1.value) }
```

You should either use a collection of `@IBOutlet` or have the text fields in an array. I believe there is a way to access your properties using a `String` but from what I've read it's not reliable or not intended so I wouldn't recommend you to do that. Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: I was very skeptical when I asked this question but I just said, SO never fails to amaze me so I did. And this worked perfectly. I have different UILabel outlets I want to assign different values to, that's why @GabrielJones suggestion will not work for me even though it might work for the scenario he suggested. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to loop through many labels and change their values, you may want to try this:

```
var i = 0
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if view is UILabel {
        titleLabel.text = items[i]
        valueLabel.text = items[i]
        i++
    }
}
```

Or, if you're trying to update 1 label's text a bunch of times rapidly, you should us an NSTimer:

```
NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

var i = 0
func update() {
    labels.text = items[i]
    i++
}
```